# My captcha is not working into my registration form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm making my registration form to which if user types correct captcha code then user's data will be stored into database, if captcha code is wrong then it'll print output as a wrong but my problem is if user enters the wrong captcha's code it will store user's data into database as well as showing "wrong code" output, pls help where i'm wrong?

here is my code.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
// show potential errors / feedback (from registration object)
if (isset($registration)) {
    if ($registration->errors) {
        foreach ($registration->errors as $error) {
            echo '<div class="alert-box error"><span>Error: </span>'.$error.'</div>';
        }
    }
    if ($registration->messages) {
        foreach ($registration->messages as $message) {
            echo '<div class="alert-box success"><span>Success: </span>'.$message.'</div>';
        }
    }
}

/** Validate captcha */
if (!empty($_REQUEST['captcha'])) {
    if (empty($_SESSION['captcha']) || trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['captcha'])) != $_SESSION['captcha']) {
        $captcha_message ="Invalid captcha";
        $style = "background-color: #FF606C color:#555
        border-radius: 0px
        font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,Arial,sans-serif font-size:11px;
        font-size: 18px
        padding:  30px 36px
        margin:10px font-weight:bold
        text-transform:uppercase border:2px solid #0c0b0b
        background-color: #ff7e48 ";

        echo'
        <div id="result" style="$style">
        <h2><div class="alert-box error"><span>error: </span>'.$captcha_message.'</div></h2>
        </div>';

    } else {
        $captcha_message = "Valid captcha";
        $style = "background-color: #CCFF99";
    }


    $request_captcha = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['captcha']);
    unset($_SESSION['captcha']);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration with Linkvessel and collaborate with college's friends</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("#datepicker").datepicker();
            });            
        </script>
        <style>
            .alert-box {
        color:#555;
        border-radius: 0px;
        font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:11px; font-size: 18px;
        padding:  30px 36px;
        margin:10px;
            }
            .alert-box span {
        font-weight:bold;
        text-transform:uppercase;
            }
            .error {
        border:2px solid #0c0b0b;
                background-color: #ff7e48;
            }

            .success{
            border:2px solid #0c0b0b;
            background-color: #a3ea42;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="document.getElementById('captcha-form').focus()">
        <div id="header">
            <img id="logo_size" src="./images/logo.png" onmousedown="return false">
        </div><br><br><br>

        <form id="form_box" method="post" action="register.php" name="registerform">
                <div id="title">
                    <h2>REGISTRATION FORM</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="controls pos_selectbox">
                    <select id="basic" name="user_college" class="input-medium">
                        <option>Select College</option>
                        <option>MAIIT kota</option>
                    </select>&nbsp; &nbsp;

                    <select id="basic" name="user_branch" class="input-medium">
                        <option>Select Branch</option>
                        <option>Computer science</option>
                        <option>Civil</option>
                        <option>Mechanical</option>
                        <option>Electrical</option>
                        <option>Bioinformatic</option>
                    </select>&nbsp; &nbsp;

                    <select id="basic" name="user_year" class="input-medium">
                        <option>Select year</option>
                        <option>1st year</option>
                        <option>2nd year</option>
                        <option>3rd year</option>
                        <option>4th year</option>
                        <option>Year completed</option>
                    </select>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                </div><br>

                <input id="input_pos" type="email" name="user_email" required="" placeholder="Email address" /><br><br>

                <input id="input_pos" type="password" name="user_password_new" required="" placeholder="Password" /><br><br>

                <input id="input_pos" type="password" name="user_password_repeat" required="" placeholder="Confirm password" /><br><br>

                <input id="name_pos" type="text" name="user_firstname" required="" placeholder="First name" />&nbsp;

                <input id="name_pos2" type="text" name="user_lastname" required="" placeholder="Last name" /><br><br>

                <input id="datepicker" type="text" name="user_dob" required="" placeholder="Date of birth" /><br><br>

                <input id="name_pos" type="text" name="user_state" required="" placeholder="State" />&nbsp;

                <input id="name_pos2" type="text" name="user_city" required="" placeholder="city" />&nbsp;<br><br>

                <img src="captcha.php" id="captcha" /><br/>

                <a href="#" onclick="
    document.getElementById('captcha').src='captcha.php?'+Math.random();
    document.getElementById('captcha-form').focus();"
    id="change-image">Not readable? Change text.</a><br/><br/>

    <input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha-form" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type code here" /><br><br>

                <input type="submit" name="register" id="pos_submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" value="Create account.."/>
            </form>
</html>
```

**EDITED**

```
<?php
    // checking for minimum PHP version
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.7', '<')) {
        exit("Sorry, Simple PHP Login does not run on a PHP version smaller than 5.3.7 !");
    } else if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0', '<')) {
        // if you are using PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.4 you have to include the password_api_compatibility_library.php
        // (this library adds the PHP 5.5 password hashing functions to older versions of PHP)
        require_once("libraries/password_compatibility_library.php");
    }

    // include the configs / constants for the database connection
    require_once("config/db.php");

    // load the registration class
    require_once("classes/Registration.php");

    // create the registration object. when this object is created, it will do all registration stuff automatically
    // so this single line handles the entire registration process.
    $registration = new Registration();

    // show the register view (with the registration form, and messages/errors)
    include("views/register.php");

?>
```

Comment: you calling register.php, can you show me file? i think you add information on database when you call register.php

Comment: Are you using any PHP framework.?

Comment: Where is ur Database Query?

Comment: @PratikJoshi: yes php login script.... i did already... pls see my edit

Comment: it's inside require_once("classes/Registration.php");

Answer (score 0):

Simple example, remove register.php and on the Else add information on database if captcha is correct.

```
/** Validate captcha */
if (!empty($_REQUEST['captcha'])) {
    if (empty($_SESSION['captcha']) || trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['captcha'])) != $_SESSION['captcha']) {
        $captcha_message ="Invalid captcha";
        $style = "background-color: #FF606C color:#555
        border-radius: 0px
        font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,Arial,sans-serif font-size:11px;
        font-size: 18px
        padding:  30px 36px
        margin:10px font-weight:bold
        text-transform:uppercase border:2px solid #0c0b0b
        background-color: #ff7e48 ";

        echo'
        <div id="result" style="$style">
        <h2><div class="alert-box error"><span>error: </span>'.$captcha_message.'</div></h2>
        </div>';

    } else {
        $captcha_message = "Valid captcha";
        $style = "background-color: #CCFF99";
       //insert in database here and redirect to index or profil
    }
    $request_captcha = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['captcha']);
    unset($_SESSION['captcha']);
}
```

and replace

```
<form id="form_box" method="post" action="register.php" name="registerform">
```

with

```
<form id="form_box" method="post" action="" name="registerform">
```

Comment: You mean i need to redirect that register.php using `header('Location: --');` over there?